# Links are not opening in default browser from anywhere

Tags: default-browser

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Then installed Brave web browser and made it default. Now when I click on any link in any application whatsoever its either a) does not do a thing (like if I click in Discord for instance) or b) CLOSE the Brave browser instead (from Telegram for instance)...

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!